# Eloquent Query Scope return Builder instead of Model when using phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, phpunit

I have the following code

```
$user = User::findByAccountCode($transaction->account_code);
```

When I execute this code on phpunit it returns an instance of  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder instead of User Model.

Here is the code for findByAccountCode

```
public function scopeFindByAccountCode($query,$account_code){


   return $query->where('account_code', $account_code)->first();

}
```

I get the following error on my Application

> ErrorException: Argument 1 passed to
>   aunicaj\Libraries\MarkupRepository::user() must be an instance of
>   aunicaj\Models\User, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
>   given

When I use the browser its working fine but not on phpunit. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem solve turns out that my factory method in my test is using

```
factory(User::class)->make()
```

it should be

```
factory(User::class)->create()
```

Answer (score 8):

You're using **query scopes incorrectly**. They should never fetch any records (this is what your call to **first()** is doing) - they are only allowed to update the query with adding/removing constraints.

Replace

```
public function scopeFindByAccountCode($query,$account_code){
  return $query->where('account_code', $account_code)->first();
}
```

with

```
public function scopeFindByAccountCode($query,$account_code){
  return $query->where('account_code', $account_code);
}
```

and use it everywhere like the following:

```
$user = User::findByAccountCode($transaction->account_code)->first();
```

If you want to have a method in your **User** method that would return a user for given account code, feel free to create it, but don't start its name with **scope**, e.g.:

```
public static function findByAccountCode($account_code){
  return static::where('account_code', $account_code)->first();
}
```

This way your code will work as you wanted - call the following to get a single user:

```
$user = User::findByAccountCode($transaction->account_code);
```

Comment: I think you meant your static method example `public static function scopeFindByAccountCode` to be named `public static function findByAccountCode` right?