# Scope-like function to return Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951160/eloquent-query-scope-return-builder-instead-of-model-when-using-phpunit) explain that Model Scopes are not meant to return anything but a Query Builder instance and custom getters should be used to return Model instances.

**Problem**

In my case I have a `User` and `Contract` Model, where a User has many Contracts. The Contract periods may overlap, but at any given time, only the Contract with the latest start date should be considered valid (e.g. given Contract 1 from `2017-01-01` to `2017-07-31` and Contract 2 from `2017-06-01` to `2017-12-31`, for `2017-07-01` Contract 2 should be returned)

**Current solution**

Using scopes I always have to call `->first()`:

```
public function scopeByDate(Builder $query, $date) {
    return $query->whereDate('start', '<=', $date)
                 ->whereDate('end', '>=', $date)
                 ->orderBy('start', 'desc');
}
public function scopeCurrent(Builder $query) {
    return $this->scopeByDate($query, date('Y-m-d'));
}
...
$user->contracts()->byDate('some-date')->first();
$user->contracts()->current()->first();
```

**(Worse?) alternative solutions**

Otherwise I could make `byDate()` and `current()` static, accepting either a `Builder` (looks bad to me) or a `User` (even worse?) instance and manually pass the parameters like

```
public static function byDate(Builder $query, $date) {
    return $query->whereDate(...)->whereDate(...)->orderBy(...)->first();
}
...
Contract::byDate($user->contracts(), 'some-date');
```

or

```
public static function byUserAndDate(User $user, $date) {
    return $user->contracts()->where...->where...->orderBy(...)->first()
}
...
Contract::byUserAndDate($user, 'some-date');
```

**Question**

Is there some way I can call `byDate()` or `current()` directly on the query builder (relation) like scopes without passing additional parameters and return a model instance instead of a builder and having to call `first()` every time?

Comment: Why not in the user create a method like this `public function currentContract() {
    return $this->contracts()->current()->first();
}` then all you will do is `$user->currentContract()` !!

Comment: I'll do as @Maraboc says. Just wrap that logic into a method. Laravel has all this cool stuff like accessors, mutators, scopes and more but they are not to be use for every scenario.

Comment: I added an answer for that case @ingkevin it was just a suggestion but when it has liked by people why not make it as answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you case you can wrap the logic inside a method in the User model then call it if you need without the need for `->first()` :

**User Model**

```
public function currentContract() { 
    return $this->contracts()->current()->first(); 
}

public function contractByDate($date) { 
    return $this->contracts()->byDate($date)->first(); 
}
```

And for the call :

```
$user->contractByDate('some-date');
$user->currentContract();
```

Nice and clean :)

Comment: I almost had the same idea by putting the wheres on the User model's function, which seemed too coupled to me. Putting the wheres in a Contract scope and accessing it from a User's method is "Nice and clean" and makes me feel a little bit stupid. Thanks for this hint :)

Comment: Happy to help ;)